# Как обработать наведение курсора на QSystemTrayIcon?

Tags: qt, события, mouse-event, system-tray

Как можно обработать наведение мыши на tray icon. Не нашел такого сигнала в описании класса QSystemTrayIcon.

Пока, что могу отследить нажатие на кнопку "свернуть" main окна, а так же могу отследить сигнал самого icon:

```
void MainWindow::changeEvent(QEvent *event)
{
...
}

//Ф-ция для реагирования на DoubleClick по tray icon
void MainWindow::trayIconActivated(QSystemTrayIcon::ActivationReason reason)
{
    switch (reason)
    {
        case QSystemTrayIcon::Trigger:
        case QSystemTrayIcon::DoubleClick:

            //Вывести информационное окно
            this -> trayActionExecute();
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

---

Но это event окна, а мне необходимо отследить event перемещения мыши. Подскажите какие есть мысли? Может совсем надо все делать по другому расскажите как быть, заранее спасибо.

Comment: по идее нормальными средствами — ни как... но вообще странное желание...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того, чтобы установить всплывающую подсказку для пользователя, когда он наводит курсор на tray icon, не нужно использовать сигналы. Достаточно воспользоваться уже созданным методом setToolTip().

---

Для этого:

```
//Шаг1 - создаем объект класса QSystemTrayIcon 
QSystemTrayIcon trayIcon = new QSystemTrayIcon(this);

//Шаг2 - на объекте вызываем нужный метод
//Всплывающее уведомление при наведении курсора
trayIcon->setToolTip("Ваше сообщение");
```

---

После вызова этого метода, при наведении курсора на tray icon (в любой момент времени) будет выводиться сообщение, которое вы укажете в методе setToolTip.